# how to replace old DW site with new WP site?

Tags: query, uploads, customization

I'm new to Wordpress.org. I have an old Dreamweaver website that I want to replace with my new Wordpress.org site, using my same original URL. How do I do this? I need simple, easy-to-understand explanations, if possible, as I'm not very tech-savvy. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but don't forget all of us here have spent years learning our craft through hard work and determination. Our time & skill is valuable - what you're asking for is way too broad, and slightly unfair. Whilst we're happy to help out with more specific problems along your journey, we can't be expected to hold your hand the whole way.

Comment: Okay, my question was too broad, but why is it unfair? I'm not asking for eternal hand-holding,and I'm not trying to take advantage of your hard-won skill and experience. But if you have any advice to help me get started, it would be very much appreciated. Maybe in ten years, I will be an old hand at WordPress and able to pass your favour on to someone else who needs help.

Answer (score 1):

In practice there is no simple migration path from platform X to wordpress (or probably to any other platform). The reason is that usually no one moves between platforms without a very good reason, and when it happens there are usually also changes in the design to take advantage of the new platform, therefor you end up rewriting a a lot of the design. It doesn't help that automatic tools (or recipes) usually produce hard to understand code.

The above refered to moving the design, content which is separated from the design is relatively easier to move, but with DW AFAIK content is mixed with design.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It sounds like I should close down the old DW site, then create the new site in WordPress and upload it using my original URL. Is that right?

Comment: yes, that is basically the way to go. You use a plugin or pages to keep the old ULRs of the pages but you will need to write the theme.